# Define a default intro image on article submissions

Tags: articles, com-content, images, default

I'm searching a way to define a default intro image in the Joomla article creator from the core (when a user create an article if he don't add an intro image there is one by default generated from a file in my server).

---

- Template override of com_content
- Inject into something like :

```
IF content.images.length == 0 
THEN
show default image
ELSE
run normal code for displaying content images
END IF
```

Thanks to [haydenyoung on Gitter](https://gitter.im/joomla/joomla-cms) for his help.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to put this as a template override for com_content.  Depending on whether you want it to appear on the category page or single article, the file would go
**/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php
/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/article/default.php**

I would make a clone of existing view and then add code below to get the intro image:

```
<?php
$images  = json_decode($this->item->images);
$intro_image = $images->image_intro;
?>
```

this is check if empty and display:

```
<?php
if($intro_image !== '') {
       echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item);

} else { ?>
       <div class="pull-left item-image">
            <img src="images/whatever/is/your/default.jpg" alt="something" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"/>
       </div>

<?php } ?>
```

I didn't have time to test, so if there is an issue, comment and I will update my answer.

Comment: [breathes sigh of relief] This is much nicer to look at than: https://gitter.im/joomla/joomla-cms  Cheers.